# How to draw over a subview of NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, subview, drawrect

I'm trying to draw at the top of my `NSView` which has some subviews. 
In fact I'm trying to reproduce the connection line style of Interface Builder. Here is the code I'm using for the moment:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect 
{
    // Background color
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    // Draw line
    if(_connecting)
    {
        CGContextRef c = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
        [[NSColor redColor] setStroke];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, _start.x, _start.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, _end.x, _end.y);        
        CGContextSetLineWidth(c, LINE_WIDTH); 
        CGContextClosePath(c);
        CGContextStrokePath(c);
    }
}
```

The first part is to color my `NSView` (if you know an other way, tell me please 'cause I come from iPhone development and I miss the `backgroundColor` property of `UIView`)

Then if a connection if detected, I draw it with 2 `NSPoint`s. This code works but I didn't get it to draw over subviews, only on the first `NSView`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A parent view cannot draw over its subviews. You would have to place another view over the subviews and draw the line there.

Comment: I've thought this solution but I've thought this was an ugly way. Well, I'll do that.

Comment: What if I need the original subviews to receive mouse events, unobscured by the top, drawing subview?

Comment: You can override hitTest on the superview to never hit the overlay view.

Comment: How do you add an NSView on top of another?